# Meaning and origin of the word "muist"

Tags: meaning, etymology

Recently, I've noticed that the NY-Times *Wordle* game accepts the word "muist" as a five-letter word attempt. But what does it mean and where does it come from?

I've searched online and I stumbled upon a few scrabble-oriented resources that strongly indicate the word is a valid scrabble word (I assume the word is accepted by *Wordle* because the game imported some word list used for scrabble).

The meaning and origin of the word still remain unclear. scrabble-solver.com defines it as "[to powder](https://www.scrabble-solver.com/define/muist)" and following that lead I came upon an [entry in a Scots dictionary](https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/muist) that seems to define it similarly. So one hypothesis is that it's a Scots word.

However, the Collins Scrabble Dictionary website has an "[Official Word Checker](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/games/scrabble/word-finder)" tool which, for this word only says "*See* must", suggesting it is an alternative spelling of "must".

According to [scrabblewordsolver.com](https://www.scrabblewordsolver.com/define-a-word/muist/), the Collins dictionary is the only one that lists this word.

Comment: The term appears to have different meanings, for instance: ***Muist** is a Korean shamanistic religion that was the dominant religion among the Korean people before the introduction of   Mahayana Buddhism,  Confucianism, and  Protestantism into Korea and parts of Manchuria.*

Comment: Compare: Words with Friends disallows almost all abbreviations (maybe VIP). Then defines a word like *id* as short for 'identification'. Must be that the definition comes up from one source while the allowed word (Freud's word) is not defined.

Comment: More context on the use in Wordle: the author of the game is Josh Wardle, who goes by [powerlanguage on GitHub](https://github.com/powerlanguage). He doesn't have an official Wordle repository there, but there is code for something called ["Guess My Word"](https://github.com/powerlanguage/guess-my-word). It uses a [Scrabble wordlist last updated in 2018](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scrabbledict/), and the [word list itself](https://github.com/powerlanguage/guess-my-word/blob/master/wordlist/sowpods.txt) (not limited to 5-letter words) includes "muist", "muisted", "muisting", and "muists".

Comment: _...and_ the word list file itself is called `sowpods.txt`, which refers to the [former name for the Collins Scrabble Words dictionary](http://scrabbleplayers.org/w/SOWPODS). So it seems like Collins is indeed the source for the use of _muist_ in Wordle (as a variant of the verb _must_).

Comment: I would 100% bet the farm that *muist* is a typo that somehow made it into the Wordle list attemptable words. I don't see any dictionaries — Collins, Scrabble, or otherwise — that recognize this word. I will waste my first guess tomorrow on *muist* (to make sure you're not making this up) and begin my research.

Comment: @TinfoilHat it's valid in the Collins official word checker: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/games/scrabble/word-finder. I'd 100% take your bet.  Based on this and my previous notes above, _muist_ is clearly not a typo and should be found in the hard copy of the CSW dictionary.

Comment: _Muist, nuist, xiist, omicronist, piist, rhoist, sigmatist_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to John Jameson, [*An Etymological Dictionary of the Scottish Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hotTAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Etymological+Dictionary+of+the+Scottish+Language%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwA2oVChMI9cXvmbfUyAIVARhjCh0VUAcC#v=onepage&q=%22muist%20must%22&f=false) (1808), there is (or was) a word spelled *muist* in Scottish:

> **MUIST,** MUST, *s.* Musk, Border. [Cited examples:] Thy smell was fell, and stronger than *muist*. *Montgomerie, Watson's Coll.* iii. 2. Redolent odour vp from the rutis sprent, / —Aromaticke gummes, or ony fyne potioun ; / *Must*, myr, aloyes, or confectioun. *Doug. Virgil*, Prol. 401. 43.

And adding to that entry, Jameson, [*A Supplement to the Etymological Dictionary of the Scottish Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=amAJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA253&dq=%22quim+and+cosh%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAWoVChMIrdPH5bbUyAIVD5aICh2utQet#v=onepage&q=%22Muist-box%22&f=false) (1825) offers this further note:

> **MUIST,** MUST, *s.* Musk, S.} *Add :*—Hence, MUIST-BOX, *s.* A box for smelling at, a musk-box. [Cited example:] "I'll tell you news, Sirs, I carry a little *muist-box* (which is the word of God) in my bosom, and when I meet with the ill air of ill company, that's like to gar me swarf, I besmell myself with a sweet savour of it, and with the name of God, which is as ointment poured out." Mich. Bruce's Lect. &c. p. 68.

On the other hand, James Murray, [*A New English Dictionary on Historical Principles*](https://books.google.com/books?id=M6ojAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA395&dq=editions:LVjeqtPr3iMC&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqvM_K3PvuAhXGWM0KHSyTAiwQ6AEwCXoECAgQAg#v=snippet&q=%22Muist%20variant%22&f=false) (1908)—the original OED—has only this entry for *muist*:

> **MUIST,** variant of MUST *Obs.*, musk.

Presumably, if the Scottish word *muist* ever was in common or occasional use in south-of-the-border English, it fell out of use when the risk that the ill air of ill company would gar one swarf ceased to be so great that well-prepared travelers had to carry a muist-box with them as an emergency source of counter-odors.

Comment: It seems unlikely that Wordle would use a spelling of "musk" that was common only in the 18th and 19th centuries in Scotland as an answer.

Comment: Re: "Scottish (meaning Scottish English, not Gaelic)": This is a bit tricky. [Scots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scots_language) is a language closely related to Modern English (it split off during the Middle English period), separate from [Scottish English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_English). *An Etymological Dictionary of the Scottish Language* seems to be about Scots -- it regards Scottish as a separate language -- though it's possible that Jamieson didn't draw the same distinction we do today, and would regard both Scots and Scottish English as "Scottish".

Comment: @ruakh: Thanks for addressing this point. I am way out of my depth on that topic and appreciate the clarification. I will remove "meaning Scottish English" from my answer if the terminology is inaccurate.

Comment: @Greybeard The word "muist" isn't in Wordle's answer list, so it will never occur as the answer, but it is in the guess list, so people are allowed to guess it.

Comment: @TannerSwett - thanks. However, I don't think it makes much difference as all Wordle entries must be "dictionary" words (rather than regional variants.)

Comment: @Greybeard I guess the question is "which dictionary"?  Generally with these sorts of things, the programmer just re-uses some pre-existing word list. For the acceptable list, the Wordle creator probably included everything that was 5 letters long on some "list of English words" (regional, obsolete or otherwise) they found. I doubt they actually looked at the definition/usage note when they thought to include it.

Comment: @R.M. I can't discount that but usually such word games, e.g. scrabble, have a stated list of words. https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114419/what-dictionary-is-wordle-based-on gives Wordle's probably source as CSW19 (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/games/scrabble/word-finder) which does give it as an "official Word" and adds "see must" However "must" directs to the modal verb, and "muist" is no part of that.

Comment: @TannerSwett - I reread your comment of the 23rd: I was unaware that there was a "guess-list" or why there should be one. I suppose anything that has ever appeared in any form of English could, even in the rarest or an obsolete form, go in there.

Comment: @Greybeard I think the reason why there's two lists is to avoid frustration: you want solutions to be well-known words, so that people won't be annoyed that they've never heard of them. But you don't want to reject legitimate words that people consider familiar. 

Plus, an attempt doesn't need to be an honest guess at the answer, you can input something to figure out more letters/positions. So it helps to have many options.

Answer (score 5):

The Scottish trail for “muist” appears to be the more interesting one: from “[Dictionaries of the Scots Language](https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/muist)”:

***†MUIST***, n., v. Also must; moust, moost.

> I - n. 1. Musk (s.Sc. 1808 Jam.), in comb. muist-ball, a perforated ball containing musk or perfume.
>
> - Sc. 1734 J. Spotiswood Hope's Practicks 538:
>   *A Silver Muist-ball.*
>
> 2 - Hair powder or flour used as a substitute for this (Sc. 1808 Jam.). Adj. mousty, moostie, powdered.
>
> - *Sc. 1796 Scots Mag. (Nov.) 770:
>   I think ye [a hairdresser] might exemption make, For the young bonny lasses sake, Nor moost nor guinea frae them take.
>   Gsw. 1797 J. Strang Gsw. Clubs (1856) 583:
>   Diel's in the worrie-cow! Is he gaun to pollute my hail kirn o' milk wi' his ill-faured greasy gab and moosty pash?
>   Dmf. 1836 A. Cunningham Lord Roldan III. xi.:
>   Thae carles [priests] wi' the mousty heads and wide sark sleeves, and curious cloaks.*
>
> II.-  v. To apply hair powder, to powder a wig. Ppl.adj. muisted, mousted, moostet (Gsw. 1807 J. Chirrey Misc. Poetry 103), powdered.
>
> - *Sc. 1761 Magopico (1810) 33:
>   What's that you laugh at, you there with the moosted twa-tailed wig and the lang ruffles?
>   Edb. 1795 The Complaint 5:
>   Nae mair the pu'pit maun he speel, Wi' head well muisted owr wi' meal.
>   Sc. 1816 Scott Antiquary x.:
>   Would ye creesh his bonny brown hair wi' your nasty ulyie, and then moust it like the auld minister's wig?
>   Sc. 1827 C. I. Johnstone Eliz. de Bruce I. iii.:
>   It matters little . . . whether the idol of the vain unsanctified heart be a tea-cup, a weel-mousted periwig, or the fair face of an enticing maiden.*

[O.Sc. moist, 1488, must, 1513, must, O.Fr. must, variant of musc, musk.]

Answer (score 2):

The OED has no entry for "muist" but has mu, noun<sup>3</sup> and interjection.

> **Etymology:** < Japanese *mu* nothingness (13th cent.; 1603 in Vocabulario da Lingoa de Iapam), use as noun of mu nothing (especially in conventional sayings), no, not, (as prefix) un-, without, -less < Middle Chinese (compare Chinese (Cantonese) mòuh , Chinese (Mandarin) wú no, not, nothing). Compare mushin n., no-decision n. (b) at *no* adj. Compounds 4.
>
> *Zen Buddhism*.
>
> **A.** n.3  **A state of voidness, nothingness, or detachment which is thought to transcend the concepts of negative and positive.**
>
> 1960   B. Leach Potter in Japan x. 222   *Appreciation of the meaning of ‘Mu’, or unattachment, deeply imbedded in Taoism, Buddhism and ever present in Zen-inspired arts and crafts.*
>
> **B.** int. **Used as an alternative to answering either ‘yes’ or ‘no’, in order to reject the validity of the question.** *rare.*
>
> 1934   N. Senzaki & P. Reps Gateless Gate 9   *A monk asked Joshu, a Chinese Zen Master: ‘Has a dog Buddha-nature, or not?’ Joshu answered ‘Mu.’*

I suspect that a Mu**ist** follows the pattern of Calvan**ist**, commun**ist**, etc. as one who follows the philosophy of "mu" and/or pracises "mu".

Comment: That was also my first guess when reading the question. But I don't know of a source to back-up the claim that "muist" does come from "mu". In addition, Wordle rejects the word "muism". "Calvinist", "communist", etc., usually have a counterpart in -ism.